# WordPress plugin inbuild table data get in android

Tags: android, wordpress

How to get data from Wordpress plugins  inbuid tables in JSON format(api through). i used like called api and get the data from the wordpress tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i used wordpress REST API and REST API-Filter Fields plugin add wordpress project and response generate

Answer (score 0):

Can you please elaborate on the question that you need the data of which table? There are various methods.

i.e. if you want the data of WooCommerce, it provides in-built [API](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/).

If you want the data of custom fields or any third-party plugins, check the documentation for readymade API or you can write your own code with the use of [WPDB](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) database instance; it will help you to communicate with the database.